# Microsoft.Data.Edm not found (Azure Functions v3.1.4)

Tags: odata, azure-functions

I have created an Azure Functions project using .NET Core v2 and attempted to migrate it to Azure Functions v3. After upgrading it complains that it cannot find `Microsoft.Data.Edm, Version=5.8.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35` anymore. When I look in the `bin` folder of my v2.1 version, then this file is copied to that location. My v3.1 version lacks a lot of files, including `Microsoft.Data.Edm.dll`. It seems the file is copied to the bin folder, but it is being removed afterwards. Does any one know what is happening?

It seems the problems start happening when the `Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions` package is upgraded to a version higher than 1.0.31. To illustrate the problem I have created a very simple Azure Function solution that contains both the V2 and the V3 version. It can be found at https://github.com/ramondeklein/AzureFunctionsWithEdm.

When running the `AzureFunctionsWithEdm2` the call http://localhost:7071/api/EdmFunction returns OK, but with `AzureFunctionsWithEdm3` it fails, because it cannot load the `Microsoft.Data.Edm` assembly. When the `Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions` package is upgraded to 1.0.33, then the V2 also fails to work.

Comment: What about using 3.0.3 of Azure Function package when you using V3?

Comment: @BowmanZhu It starts failing from version 1.0.33, but I found a workaround after spitting around in the Azure Functions repo for a while...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that the `RemoveRuntimeDependencies` task removes this assemblies ([source](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/commit/1ed2a54159eb3c9aaff11a9289be2bf1ce91dcb5#diff-8924132f0d2b330a1888e0f17c5fcdb4R27)). It doesn't run when the `_FunctionsSkipCleanOutput` variable is set to `true`. Adding the following line effectively disables this task and makes it work for 1.0.33 and later too.

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <_FunctionsSkipCleanOutput>true</_FunctionsSkipCleanOutput>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Item is tracked via [this issue](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/issues/5894).